# How can $m(x-1)<x+2$ be solved

Tags: inequality

Today my professor gave us some problems that might be on next week's exam, one of them being this. Haven't learned this earlier and only explained how to solve $mx>3$. I've been trying to solve this for the past hour, but haven't gotten near a full result. The only thing I can be 99% sure about is that when $m=0$ then $x>-2$. But I can't figure it out for positive and negative numbers. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m=0$ you're right, you have $x>-2$.

If not, expand it: $m(x-1)=mx-m$, so $mx-m<x+2$ and then $mx-x<m+2$, from which we can take common factor $x$, $(m-1)x<m+2$.

If $m=1$ then we get $0<m+2$ which implies $m>-2$. This is true in the case we are considering, $m=1$, so any real number $x$ satisfies the inequality. The solution is $\Bbb R$.

If $m<1$ then $m-1<0$ and so $\dfrac{1}{m-1}<0$, hence when multiplying the inequality by $\dfrac{1}{m-1}$ we have to change $<$ for $>$. Therefore we get $x>\dfrac{m+2}{m-1}$.

If $m>1$ then $m-1>0$ and so $\dfrac{1}{m-1}>0$ and we can multiply the inequality by $\dfrac{1}{m-1}$ maintaining the $<$, so we get $x<\dfrac{m+2}{m-1}$.

We've covered all cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's $$(m-1)x<m+2.$$
Now, if $m>1$, we obtain: $$x<\frac{m+2}{m-1},$$ if $m<1$ we obtain: $$x>\frac{m+2}{m-1}$$ and  if $m=1$ we obtain $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $m(x-1)-(x+2)=x(m-1)-(m+2)$ so the inequality is the same as $$x(m-1)<(m+2)$$

Clearly it's true to $m=1$ for any $x$.

If $m>1$ then we have $x<\frac{m+2}{m-1}$

And if $m<1$ then $m-1<0$ so $x>\frac{m+2}{m-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $x$,

$$m(x-1)<x+2$$

so that

$$(m-1)x<2+m.$$

Now you have to distinguish three cases, depending on the sign of $m-1$:

- $m>1\to x<\dfrac{2+m}{m-1}$;
- $m<1\to x>\dfrac{2+m}{m-1}$;
- $m=1\to 0<3$, which is true for any $x$.